# Return from function with the return value of a callback (nested functions)?

Tags: jquery

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), 'validate');
    return .....;
});

function validate(data) {
    return data;
}
```

I need to return from the submit function the result that the validate() provides (data). How do I do that? How to make the return of the submit wait until the ajax returns result?

Comment: The `validate()` function in the `$.post` fires only after the AJAX Request has been successfully completed. What you have done is right. Now what's the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because it's asynchronous.

You can do this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the form from submitting

    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        if( validate( data ) ) {
            form.submit(); //Now submit the form. Please note `form` is not a jQuery object the event handler is not triggered.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Won't form.submit() call the anonymous function again and therefore trigger the ajax request again?

Comment: @ГеоргиГеоргиев `form.submit()` calls the native submit method of the form, since `form` is a DOM element not a jQuery object. If it was a jQuery object you would be right because calling `submit()` on a jQuery object will trigger the jQuery event + call the native `submit` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the method looks confusing. May be you should initialize a variable to False during page load, and set it to true, after the validate function returns successful data. It can be set inside a conditional like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  if (!postflag) {
         e.preventDefault();
          $.post("foo.php",serialize(),function(data) {
                   if (validate(data)) {
                             postflag = true;
                    }
          });
        }  
    if (postflag) {
        $(this).submit();
     }          
     });
```